# Laplacian in a spherical coordinate system question

Tags: laplacian, curvilinear-coordinates

Q: Consider a function f = r^2 given in the spherical coordinate system. Using the expression for the scale factors, as well as the formula for the Laplacian compute the Laplacian ∇^2 f . The result is a number times r^(n-2) . State this number.

Not sure where I've gone wrong with this, I think I'm close to the answer but I can't seem to get r^(n-2), or get rise of cosec(theta). I'll show my workings:

f = r^2 hr = 1 htheta = r hphi = rsintheta

grad f = 1/hr * ∂f/∂r * **e**r + 1/htheta * ∂f/∂theta * **e**theta + 1/hphi * ∂f/∂phi * **e**phi

= 2r **e**r

**∇** . **A** = 1/h1h2h3 [∂(h2h3A1)∂u1 + ∂(h1h3A2)/∂u2 + ∂(h1h2A3)/∂u3]

**∇** = 2r**e**r = A1**e**1 where A1 = Ar = 2r

**∇** . **A** = 1/hr*htheta*hphi (∂(r * rsintheta * A1)/∂r + ∂(1 * rsintheta * A2)/∂theta + ∂(1 * r * A3)/∂phi)

Now A2 = A3 = 0, A1 = 2r

**∇** . **A** = 1/r^2*sin^2theta * ∂/∂r (r^2 * sin(theta) *2r)

= 1/r^2*sin^2theta * ∂/∂r (2r^3 sin(theta))

= 1/r^2*sin^2 (theta) * 6r^2 sin(theta)

= 6/sin(theta)

Now I know that the correct answer is 6, so am I correct? Is my working correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax formatting for mathematical expressions. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You will not get $r^{-2}$.  Dimensional analysis forces the exponent on $r$ to be two less than the function you put in when you take a second derivative; thus $r^2$ will give a Lapacian with $r^0$ not $r^{-2}$.  The book must have made a mistske.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must admit I find our OP Sam Connell's question a little unclear; nevertheless I feel I can make enough sense out of it to give it a try, so here goes:

We first find $\nabla^2 r^2$ in three dimensions:

By definition we have

$\nabla^2 r^2 = \nabla \cdot (\nabla r^2); \tag 1$

it is both well-known and easy to see (e.g. by working in cartesian coordinates) that

$\nabla r^2 = \dfrac{d(r^2)}{dr} \nabla r = 2r \nabla r; \tag 2$

$\nabla r = \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial r} \hat e_r = \hat e_r, \tag 3$

where $\hat e_r$ denotes the unit vector field tangent to the radial lines and pointing in the outward direction; combining (2) and (3) yields

$\nabla r^2 = 2r \hat e_r; \tag 4$

thus,

$\nabla^2 r^2 = \nabla \cdot (2r \hat e_r) = \nabla (2r) \cdot \hat e_r + 2r \nabla \cdot \hat e_r$
$= 2\nabla r \cdot \hat e_r + 2r \nabla \cdot \hat e_r = 2 \hat e_r \cdot \hat e_r + 2r \nabla \cdot \hat e_r = 2 + 2r \nabla \cdot \hat e_r, \tag 5$

where we have exploited the well-known identity $\nabla \cdot (fX) = \nabla f \cdot X + f \nabla \cdot X$, holding for any differentiable function $f$ and vector field $X$; here $f = 2r$ and $X = \hat e_r$; now,

$\hat e_r = r^{-1} \vec r, \tag 6$

and it is easy to compute that

$\nabla \cdot \vec r = 3, \tag 7$

since $\vec r = (x, y, z) \in \Bbb R^3$; therefore,

$\nabla \cdot \hat e_r = \nabla \cdot (r^{-1} \vec r) = \nabla (r^{-1}) \cdot \vec r + r^{-1} \nabla \cdot r$
$= -r^{-2} \hat e_r \cdot \vec r + r^{-1}\nabla \cdot \vec r$
$= -r^{-2} r + 3r^{-1} = 2r^{-1}; \tag 8$

$\nabla^2 r^2 = 2 + 2r\nabla \cdot \hat e_r = 2 + 2r(2r^{-1}) = 6. \tag 9$

Comment: I think it's just a poor question on my lecturer's part. The question implies a r^(n-2) in the resulting equation, asking for its multiplier. But the resulting equation gives no r^(n-2) unless my lecturer meant in the occasion where n = 2? That was the essence of the question I was asking, my working was correct in terms of method but my 1/hrhthetahphi should have been (r^2 sin(theta))^-1 not (r^2 sin^2 (theta))^-1; which I did

Comment: @SamConnell:  first of all, I wish you would learn and exploit $LaTeX$/mathjax properly so your posts are easier to read.  But no big deal; I found your question enough fun to answer even if is hard to follow.  As for the case $\nabla^2 r^m$, I plan to add that to my answer before too long.  Do these remarks add clarity for you?  If not, please feel free to ask more questions.  ***Cheers!!!***